# Music player program that reads star ratings from Windows

Tags: music, migration, metadata, mediaplayer

I used Winamp on Windows. This allowed me to rate songs using a 5 star system. These star ratings are stored in the files as metadata. I could view the star rating in file properties in Winamp and Windows Explorer.

Now I have switched to Mac. I want a music player that reads and writes the same star rating in the file metadata. Is there one?

Comment: is winamp for mac not working for you?

Comment: It works but seems to have very few features compared to Windows version. It doesn't seem to show star ratings at all